# Android - How to calculate inclination in relevance to a starting position

Tags: android, android-sensors, device-orientation

I calculate the inclination of the device using sensorManager.

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rmat, Imat, gData, mData);
SensorManager.getOrientation(Rmat, orientation)
float incl = SensorManager.getInclination(Imat);
incl = (float) Math.toDegrees(incl);
```

When the device is perpendicular to the ground, it shows 0 degrees, and when the device is flat (parallel to the ground), it shows 90 degrees.

My question is how can I calibrate the inclination sensor in order to calculate the degrees in relevance to a starting position of the device?

E.g If the device is flat and user presses "Callibrate", inclination value will become zero degrees, and as the device moves up to a perpendicular position, inclination value becomes 90 degrees

Comment: _"If the device is flat and user presses "Callibrate", inclination value will become zero degrees"_ You'll just use the measured inclination as on offset. If it's 90 degrees you'll use that as a correction value and calculate 90 - 90 to get zero. What more is there to it? Then after calibration you move the phone to a "real" inclination of 80 and you again deduct 90 and get -10 and so on until a new calibration is done.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Thank you. The problem though was elsewhere. The inclination given is the geomagnetic Inclination which has nothing to do with the angle of the actual device. However, you've answered my question and I will accept it if you add it as an answer.

Comment: I don't think I fully understood the question and the comment was rather trivial, so I won't add an answer. You can also add an answer yourself, if you came up with a solution to your problem. That's okay.

Comment: Can you please show the snippet of how you get the parameters for these functions?